# How do i change the url of my phpmyadmin?

Tags: url, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I used wampserver to create a phpmyadmin server but the URL in my browser is set to localhost/phpmyadmin. I want to know how I can change it to something more specific like my ip/phpmyadmin which can then be used by my friends to access the databases on it.

How would I go about doing such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localhost/phpmyadmin is just the url for you, because the server is on your computer.
If you want your friends can use phpmyadmin, you just have to give them your ip/domain and they will access it with ip/phpmyadmin.

You'll maybe need to configure your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You will also have to set up port forwarding on you router so port 80 is forwarded to your PC running wamp. 
You will also need to change this file
C:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf

Change it from

```
<Directory "d:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

TO

```
<Directory "d:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This will of course mean anybody in the world can access your phpmyadmin unless you have a very good and strong password assigned to 'root'